# hive search 2 columns are present in a single column in second table

Tags: hadoop, hive

Have 2 tables in hive like. Table 2 is a master table with billions of records.

Table 1

```
name| id1 | id2
jac | 1   | 2
rac | 3   | 1
```

Table 2

```
class | id
first | 1
second| 3
```

How can I write an efficient query in hive to search both id1 and id2 from table 1 are present in table 2 and isolate those records?

Thanks
ms

Answer (score 0):

Probably `JOIN` is the best method:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2a
     on t1.id1 = t2a.id join
     table2 t2b
     on t1.id2 = t2b.id;
```

In other databases, `EXISTS` or `IN` might be better, particularly with indexes.  My guess is that a simple `JOIN` works best in Hive.